# WordPress custom theme errors with showing content

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress `index.php` errors

```php
<?php
get_header();
get_content();
get_footer();
?>
```

The `footer.php` is not showing, and when I remove the `get_content()` footer is working normally.

Comment: can you check what's in content.php file which could cause the bug. Perhaps two calls of the footer???

Comment: Please add the code of your page.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `while` loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :

    print_r(get_the_content())


endwhile; // End the loop.
```

It's worked. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

with this while is not working.

when i try to put this

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_header('content'); ?>
<?php get_footer('footer'); ?>
```

with created header-content.php file.The footer is gona,is not showing,and content is showing only first 5 lines